# Have 20 Access 97 DB's and need to migrate to Web Base

Tags: ms-access, migration

I am being assigned as supervisor of the IT department. I have to convert 20 or so Access97 databases into a web-based application. Windows Server and desktop are the standard. IIS will be the web hosting platform and we have MS-SQL as the backend.

What method or programming language would you recommend? I was thinking ASP because of the easy functionality with IIS.

Thank you.

Comment: I can't quite see why this is marked off-topic. There are quite a number of similar questions on SO.

Answer (score 2):

I’m going through a similar process “upgrading” a few access applications to some flavour of .Net with a SQL server backend. I did it in two stages, first I migrated the data then migrated the applications one at a time.

One thing I would say is unless there is a good reason don’t always push everything into web applications. Web apps have come a long way but there are still times where a desktop application will offer a better user experience and a lot of the zero install benefits of web applications are not too bad in a managed IT environment.

Where I have chosen to go the web route I have used Visual Web Developer 2008 Express, its free and quite simple to get your head around if you know VB/VB.Net.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you pick a development platform you are familiar with/can learn quickly, I think this is the least of your problems.

I'm guessing this verdict came from up top. No one who is relying on these applications would make such a blanket request.

Identify the appllication that make the most sense to move to a website based on functionality (See Kevin Ross). The apps that can benefit from a centralized, secured data entry front end are your best candidates. You may have users that are using access as a custom reporting tool. They want to be able to run ad hoc queries and export things to Excel for further analysis. Also, consider working with one department at a time. There is going to be push back from users. You're going to be taking their time to learn their apps, have them test the new site, check the data conversions, etc.